# Laravel registering routes affecting CSS

Tags: css, laravel, url, laravel-routing

I am using Laravel 6 and want to change the structure of some of my routes in the `web.php` file. When registering the following route like this:

```
Route::view('/my-article', 'articles.my-article')->name('my-article');
```

everything works as it should.

But when changing the URL like this, adding `/articles`:

```
Route::view('/articles/my-article', 'articles.my-article')->name('my-article');
```

Suddenly no CSS is applied anymore. No Bootstrap, Fontawesome or own stylesheet. JS script on the other hand, and HTML of course, were loaded.
Oddly (for me): The other routes worked fine, all CSS stylesheets loaded.

I tried the same with another route that had a Controller action. I changed it from

```
Route::get('/{continent}', 'ContinentController@index')->name('continent');
```

to (adding `/continents`)

```
Route::get('/continents/{continent}', 'ContinentController@index')->name('continent');
```

And again, no styles were applied. Only JS scripts and HTML.
Why is that so? Why can't I add something to the URL by hand and why does it affect the loading of the CSS stylesheets?

Thanks and best regards.

**EDIT:**

Here is the part of my `template.blade.php` file where the styles are included:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Font Awesome Icons CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<!-- Own CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css?{{ time() }}">
```

Comment: don't use relative paths to things

Comment: You mean I should use absolute paths in the web.php file?